# Apple HLS offline video playing can not play 2 videos if internet not available

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, offline, http-live-streaming

I am streaming and download to  offline 4 videos simultaneously by using [Apple HLS Catelog](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HLSCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html)

I could successfully download the videos.

Then, I am trying to view four videos offline by using 4 `AVPlayer` instance

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: (asset.urlAsset))
let player1 = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
player1.play()
```

There is a strange behaviour, only first paying video is Playing (All videos are successfully downloaded).This condition remains the same if the videos are interchanged.

This video is reading from an IP-Camera by using my own python application and upload to cloud server.
But, I could successfully play all videos (4 videos) concurrently when using a sample mp4 which is downloaded from internet.

Comment: offline paying?  The title has a serious typo.

Comment: it is working fine if internet is available (not streaming by using url. playing from local downloaded asset only')

Comment: I guess you are talking about Apple Pay, then.

Comment: No, video offline playing

Comment: El Tomoto: I have updated the title

Comment: @ElTomato: Any Idea about the issue.

Comment: Just curious, how does your URL looks like? Is it pointing to a Live Playlist?

Comment: @jjramos: I found my issue.

Comment: @VineeshTP do you mind sharing your findings?

Comment: It was my mistake, When download I used different names for each videos, So I could successfully downloaded the vides. But, When playing I was used same asset name for all offline videos. So, It is always playing first video only.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, When download I used different names for each videos, So I could successfully downloaded the vides. But, When playing I was used same asset name for all offline videos. So, It is always playing first video only.